# How can I merge summed data to non-summed data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge two data frames together, based on PSID and 'location'. One data frame comes to me summed and one comes to me non-summed.

Here is the summed DF:

[image]

Here is the non-summed DF:

[image]

I want to keep the 'activity' field and sum the 'spending' in the second dataframe while merging the first dataframe and second dataframe together, based on PSID and location. I tried this, but of course it didn't work.

```
df_combined = pd.merge(df_first, df_second, left_on='PSID', right_on='location', how='inner')
```

The problem with this is that the 'REV' gets duplicated in the 'df_combined'.

Comment: So you want to get 1 row or 2 with the data merged ?  If just 1, how do you want to keep 2 values of 'activity' field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try, transform sum before we merge; Happy to review if this is not what you want.

calc spending sum

```
g=df_second.assign(spending_sum=df_second.groupby('location')['spending'].transform('sum'))
```

merge

```
df_combined = pd.merge(df_first, g, left_on='PSID', right_on='location', how='left')
```

This will be the chained solution though not so readable

```
df_combined = pd.merge(df_first, df_second.assign(spending_sum=df_second.groupby('location')['spending'].transform('sum')), left_on='PSID', right_on='location', how='left')
```

Comment: I think this does work. I had to drop NAs or use an 'inner join' to get what I wanted. Also, I found out that the solution below works, as well.  

df_full = pd.merge(df_first, 
                df_second.drop_duplicates(subset=['location'], 
                keep='first'), 
                left_on='PSID',
                right_on='location',
                how='inner')